# Embedding web browser window in Java

Tags: java, swing, browser, embed

Does anyone know a way to open up an instance of the operating system (Windows/Linux/Mac) browser within a Swing window that is integrated into a Java application. No other actions would be performed other than opening a given URL. Currently, we open a new browser window because the Java embedded browsers have been insufficient. However, from a user interaction standpoint this is less than desirable.

I'm curious if a solution for this was part of the 1.6 Java release. So far my google searching has not turned up anything of note. Are there any closed-source libraries that do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Your link is broken. Although I am using Chrome, so if it isn't, it's only my problem.

Comment: Documentation was here: 1) http://www.aswinanand.com/2006/03/two-minute-web-browser-in-java/

Comment: it would be wonderful if this answer could be expanded to include some description of how the solution works rather than just a link.

Answer (score 1):

use [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

> A text component to edit various kinds of content. By default, the following types of content are known: text/plain, text/html and text/rtf

or [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp)

> Lobo is an open source web browser that is written completely in Java.

Comment: The OP asked about opening the platform browser.

Answer (score 1):

We use JDIC as well and it works for us in Windows; however, configuring it to work in *nix/OS X can be a pain, as it simply utilizes a platform-native browser (supports IE and Mozilla), while on Linux/Mac you may have neither - that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[WebRenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/) is a commercial product that does this, and does it well. However, the last time I checked it was also pretty expensive (they wanted a $2 per-client fee for a *large* number of client, and a several $1000 support contract).

Answer (score 1):

MozSwing it is free  or JxBrowser or JExplorer ($500)