# Java & Google Maps

Tags: java, google-maps

Is it possible to render google maps in swing or applet?

I know i can also use [NASA World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/) but it seems to much overkill for a simple app.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/java-api-for-google-maps-or-similar

Comment: The linked question was just after a static image in their app.  Hamza were you after the panning and zooming stuff as well?

Comment: @Hamza, ok so the static map solution is not going to suit you.  Not sure if you have any other options for a Java app.

Answer (score 3):

There is JXMapViewer component in SwingX project. You can write new TileProviderInfo,TileFactory to pull images from Google maps but using JXMapViewer to pull maps from Google was illegal when I used it(2008). Google was usually changing Map URL format so your program can be broken unexpectedly if this is still illegal.

in My last project we have used JXMapViewer and Microsoft Visual Earth instead of Google maps.

Comment: There is a layer in Worldwind to pull the ms visual earth images already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JxMaps](https://teamdev.com/jxmaps) to render Google Maps in your Swing application. It provides Java API that covers most of Google Maps JavaScript API functionality.