# how can i use JXMapViewer in my applet?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, swingx, jxmapviewer

i want to write an applet that must render my map images with zoom/pan tools,
i find out JXMapViewer can help me,
how i can use it?
 where i can find related docs which help me to write an applet that request on my image server to provide tiles to render?
what about image server and .... !!!!???
help me on : image server structure, tileprovider, tilefactory,... that JXMapViewer need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As AeonFlux linked you, Joshua Marinacci's blog is the best resource to get started. There are six articles he wrote that I have used to get up to speed with JXMapViewer. In order of publication:

- [Getting started with the Aerith Mapping Component](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/07/getting_started.html)
- [NASA Maps in your Swing App](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/10/nasa_maps_in_yo.html)
- [A Mapping Christmas Present](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/12/a_mapping_chris.html)
- [Tricked out maps and a new tile provider](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2007/02/tricked_out_map.html)
- [Building Maps into Your Swing Application with the JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)
- [Mapping Mashups with the JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/13/mapping-mashups-with-jxmapviewer.html)

In addition, here are some other resources I have found useful:

- [SwingLabs forums](http://forums.java.net/jive/forum.jspa?forumID=73), where you can ask questions about JXMapViewer
- [SwingX-WS Continuous Build (Hudson)](http://swinglabs.java.sun.com/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/), where you can download the latest version of SwingX-WS

The best combination of functionality I have found uses the latest continuous build of SwingX-WS, which is that JAR built on April 16, 2008 ([direct link](http://swinglabs.java.sun.com/hudson/job/SwingX-WS%20Continuous%20Build/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/swingx-ws.jar)). However, some things have changed in SwingX-1.0 and that latest SwingX-WS JAR won't work with SwingX-1.0. So I had to download [SwingX 0.9.7](https://swingx.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11187&expandFolder=11187&folderID=0) ([direct link to the JAR](https://swingx.dev.java.net/files/documents/2981/131985/swingx-0.9.7.zip)). You'll need both the **swingx-0.9.7.jar** file as well as the **swingx-beaninfo-0.9.7.jar**.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some links that can probably help

[Link 1](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)

older [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072709/java-google-maps) from Stack Overflow where a similar question was put up.

[Link2](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/13/mapping-mashups-with-jxmapviewer.html)