# Is there a Swing component for Google Maps?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, components

I would like to have support for Google Maps in my Java Swing desktop application. Is there an Google Maps component for Swing that is freely available? It would be good if it was extendable and maybe had support for other maps i.e. like OpenStreetMaps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use JXMapViewer
look here 
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Oracle has closed Java.net. Please take a look here https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2

Answer (score 12):

How about [JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)?  Looks like it gets NASA's Blue Marble tile set by default (if you want 3D maps and Blue Marble [WorldWindJava](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) is an amazing API for mapping), but also works with OpenStreetMap.  Or, looks like [gmap-viewer](http://code.google.com/p/gmap-viewer/) is a project which can show you how it's done.  [Aerith](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/aerith_a_very_cool_swing) also includes Google maps.

EDIT: Also, check out this related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/java-api-for-google-maps-or-similar).  Looks like the FAQ, at least at that time, did not allow you to do what you want with Google Maps (OpenStreetMap, on the other hand, has desktop apps like [Traveling Salesman](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman) and clearly embraces the desktop, as does WorldWind).

Answer (score -3):

You can use Google visualisation library directly in java, where you can show Google Maps as you like.

[Google Visualization API Gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)

Comment: How can I use Google visualisation in Java Swing? As what I understand they are only available for web applications.