# Embed google maps in Java desktop Application

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I want to embed google maps on a JPanel. Since I want features like zoom-in/out, using static images isn't feasible.

To achieve this, I'll probably need to embed a webpage (which displays google maps) in my Java desktop application. And I've read that I'll need something like WebKit (alternatives?) to accomplish this.

I'd appreciate any help that'll help me:

1. Embed a webpage in a Jpanel.
2. That webpage to display google maps.

Comment: Try the answers given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737363/is-there-a-swing-component-for-google-maps). :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the Google Maps APIs can now be used in Desktop applications

Check out these Stack Overflow threads:

[Google Map in JAVA Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598074/google-map-in-java-swing)

[Embedding Gecko/Webkit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java)

[Webkit browser in a Java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app)

[Rendering webpages with WebKit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850338/rendering-webpages-with-webkit-in-java)

You can also see the [tutorail](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html) of using Maps in Java Desktop Application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JxMaps](https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps) library to complete this task. It has Swing component which can be simply embedded to `JPanel`.

```
void createMapView(JPanel parent) {
    MapView view = new MapView();
    parent.add(view);
}
```

This library has comprehensive set of classes for working with Google Maps from java.

Comment: great product ... unfortunately is not open source

Comment: It's not open-source, but it's free for open-source and academic projects: https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps#evaluate