# Embedding maps in java swing application

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I'm developing a java swing application in which i need to show the map of some area and allow user to put markers on it.
I've goggled a lot on the topic but unfortunately i haven't got any how i can do it. 
I came across some ideas like displaying a web browser in swing just like JXBrowser (i can't afford JXBrowser).
And i'm also not sure if this way will allow me adding markers.

Please guide me some proper way to do the trick.
Please do tell me if i can do it offline or online any way suitable.

Comment: Did you check out what Google maps offer?

Comment: checkn this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701105/embed-google-maps-in-java-desktop-application).

Comment: Yes i did checked it out and i figured out that google now allows its users to integrate google maps in desktop apps, but how i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/APIs)? In particular [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM)

Comment: Yes i have seen JOSM.
I Found out JXMapViewer and JMapViewer are some ways to integrate maps in swing,
but i cannot find any their jar's and samples because Swinglabs website no more exists.

Comment: If it was me... I'd try and embed a browser and do it via javascript.

Comment: how can i handle scripting in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java