# How to use Google Static Map in java.swing

Tags: swing, google-maps-static-api

i new to using google maps in java. Can some one recommend me a good tutorial or resource that explains everything in detail (step by step).
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [*Google Maps APIs: Which API do I need?*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)

Comment: See also [*Embed google maps in Java desktop Application*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19701105/230513)