# Good solution to integrate Google Map in Java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I want integrate a Map inside a Jpanel where I can set latitude and longitude,  move the map location, drag, etc.. (like google map web) I don't see any Java desktop application with this function and not recent info about this. I want a free solution for this.

I am currently testing goole api services. But They provide me the info but not the map integration.

There are other solutions that I am not investigating?

- [Embed google maps in Java desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701105/embed-google-maps-in-java-desktop-application) (2013)
- [Is there a Swing component for Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737363/is-there-a-swing-component-for-google-maps) (JXMapViewer - java.net page closed and not found the real article)

  - [Google Map in JAVA Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598074/google-map-in-java-swing) (Can't use static map in desktop, TOS violation)
  - [Embedding Gecko/WebKit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embedding-gecko-webkit-in-java) (JxBrowser, paid / JavaXPCOM not active)

Comment: Java-FX offers an embeddable browser..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JXMapViewer` was a part of SwingLabs, which brought us also SwingX, but with java.net no longer available, it's webpage is no longer reachable.

There is a fork of `JXMapViewer` named `JXMapViewer2`, which seems better maintained and offers also examples how to use it: https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try :)