# how to display a map in jframe

Tags: jframe

I would like to display a map inside a jframe. More specifically, I don't want to display a static map, image.

I would like to display a map like google map with all the utilities like panning/zooming etc.

Could you help me?? Is there any reference code??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [OpenMap](http://www.openmap.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently jFrames doesn't seem to support Google Maps.

[Google Maps - Issues](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/google-maps)

You may want to look into alternatives, such as using an iFrame?

[Google Maps Embedding Tutorial](http://ongopongo.com/maps/google_my_maps_embedding_tool)

or

[Google's How-To for Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it isn't exactly what i want. More specifically, it is about a java desktop application that will display (in jframe if possible) maps. Any idea??

Comment: I just found this - I'm not terribly familiar with desktop java apps, but hopefully you might can find something useful on here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/java-api-for-google-maps-or-similar