# Java API for creating Google Maps or Earth

Tags: java, google-maps

I am looking for a Java API to access Google Maps or preferably Google Earth. But seem to be have problems finding the right solution after searching the web.

From a Java desktop application, I want t be able to create a map with about 1,000 custom points on which will have been pre-geocoded with Long/Lat. Once the application has created the map (with points on), I want the application to show the user the results.

I know you can't embed a map in an application due to T&C's of the service, so would be happy to launch a browser session, or preferably launch Earth and auto show the map on that.

I did find the Google Maps Web Services API, which let me do the geo-coding from Java using JSON, but can't find anything like this for actually creating maps and adding points to maps.

I also found some old java GDATA API's, but these seem deprecated now.

Any advise on the best current way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the static google maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps) documentation? maybe you could create the link to call that from your java program and then open it in a browser.

Comment: your question was comprehensively discussed before. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/java-api-for-google-maps-or-similar)

Comment: I read that thread before posting. It is more about displaying the map. It does not really cover the main part of my question which was more about how to create a build a custom map, which custom points on, via java

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [JxMaps](https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps) product to integrate map to Java desktop application. Custom points can be displayed as markers.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the google map documentation of geocoding API

here is the link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33042990)