# Use google map with java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I want to  develop java swing application with Google map. But I could not be succeed. I have another problem is it possible with swing applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JXMapViewer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html).

For More Look on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996954/java-api-for-google-maps-or-similar)

Comment: Please **Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.